# How to execute a propel query?

Tags: execution, propel

how to execute a propel query?

For example this:

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add(AuthorPeer::NAME, $name);
```

I know Doctrine method is execute() but using propel?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add(AuthorPeer::NAME, $name);
$result = AuthorPeer::doSelect($c);
```

For more details, see the [reference](http://www.propelorm.org/wiki/Documentation/1.4/BasicCRUD).

or [see this](http://propel.posterous.com/propel-gets-collections) for the iterable collection way (Propel 1.5+).